# Ubuntu One uploads unchanged data frequently

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, sync

I ran into the following issue: I'm using Ubuntu One to sync my files (across multiple computers), for what it's intended.

But due to some mysterious reason it promts to me, that there will be some files uploaded. And this again and again and so on.

Plus, when I want to shut down my computer and dismiss the desktop session, I'm notified, that Ubuntu One is currently running or hung up unexpected.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is but you can get more detail about what is being up/down loaded by installing `Magicicada` It lists the files and metadata being queued by U1 you need to add this ppa `ppa:chicharreros/ppa` to install

Comment: the problem is, that ubuntu one is permanantly syncing my files without need. In addtion to that, it hungs up. But anyway, I will give `Magacicada` a try.

Comment: ubuntuone-indicator is another option for being aware of what Ubuntu One is doing. Not as much info as Magiciada but has the advantage of being an indicator so status is always visible. FYI: you can terminate if Ubuntu One is running, it will pick up where it left off when Ubuntu is next booted.

Comment: u1sdtool --current-transfers will list all the Uploads/Downloads going on in the client. FWIW I'm syncing multiple computers without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could figure this one out, U1 uploads the smallest files first to shrink the queue of pending files as fast as possible. You can monitor this using a terminal and type:

```
while true; do u1sdtool --waiting|wc -l; sleep 20;done
```

That will give you a neat integer with number of files left.

The "ubuntu notification" you get in the top right corner, which says that the same file is being uploaded is just presenting the first file on the list - and since your list might contain several large files - then that largest file may be the same number one on the list for quite some time.

If the number of files does not reduce itself then i'd recommend make an assessment: If your files are very large then compute the expected time (filesize/bandwidth), and if you think that this has passed hours ago, then restart the sync service using:

```
u1sdtool --disconnect; u1sdtool --connect
```

Then rerun the code (top) to monitor whether the number of files are reducing.